# Is anyone aware of works studying `lp metrics'.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is anyone aware of works studying what might naturally be called `$L^p$ metrics', i.e. maps $d: M \times M \to [0,\infty)$ on a space $M$ such that $d(x,z) \leq (d(x,y)^p + d(y,z)^p)^{1/p}$. Of course, this condition is stronger than the normal triangle inequality if $p > 1$, but weaker if $p < 1$, which is the case I'm curious about. Obvious examples of such spaces include $L^p(X)$ where $p < 1$.

Comment: That is, maps $d$ such that $d^p$ is a metric?

Comment: Good observation, which makes the study trivial. But what about studying `$L^p$ norms' on a vector space, i.e. maps $\| \cdot \|$ such that $\| \alpha v \| = |\alpha| \| v \|$ and $\| v + w \| \leq (\| v \|^p + \| w \|^p)^{1/p}$. Then taking things to the power of $p$ removes homogeneity.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more general object, called a *snowflake metric space*, may be of interest here.

A metric space $(X, d)$ is called a $p$-snowflake if there exists a metric $d_1$, bi-Lipschitz equivalent to $d$, such that
$$
d_1(x, z) \le \left(d_1(x,y)^p + d_1(y,z)^p \right)^{1/p} \; \text{for } \; p< \infty
$$
$$
d_1(x, z) \le \max\{ d_1(x,y), d_1(y,z) \} \; \text{for } \; p = \infty.
$$

Main examples of such spaces are fractals. Actually, they are called $p$-snowflakes because of the classical [von Koch snowflake curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) $C$, endowed with the planar Euclidean metric. It is a $p$-snowflake with $p = \log 4/ \log 3$. Indeed, one can choose 
$$
d_1(x,y) = \left(H^p(C_{xy})\right)^{1/p},
$$
where $H^p$ denotes the [Hausdorff $p$-measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure) on $C$ and $C_{xy}$ denotes the minimal connected
subset of $C$ containing $x$ and $y$.

This article contains some characterisations of such spaces:

https://www.emis.de/journals/AASF/Vol30/tyson.pdf